# db4o class model transient field

Tags: java, database, db4o, transient, object-oriented-database

I am using db4o as DBMS and I have a question:

Is there any way to specify that I do not want to store a field from the model class in the database?

Something similar to `@Transient` annotation when working with relational databases?

Comment: Thanks! Simple answer but not a stupid question... or I hope so ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the Java built in transient marker:

```
private transient String myField;
```

Or is there a special reason why you cannot use it?

Comment: Thanks! I did not think about it, and now it seems I just asked a stupid question

Comment: Its ok, I was about to ask the same stupid question. Glad you asked it first :)

Answer (score 0):

Also static Java fields are not automatically persisted by DB4O:

http://community.versant.com/documentation/reference/db4o-8.1/java/reference/Content/advanced_topics/type_handling/static_fields_and_enums/static_fields_api.htm